# Swimlane ngx-charts glitch with rotating x axis ticks

Tags: angular, charts, ngx-charts

Using ngx-charts with Angular 10, and I've found an issue with the stacked bar chart and the simple bar chart.

When I have more than 24 elements present on the bar charts, the charts start to spasm and twitch so much that the data is unreadable. If I increase or decrease padding of the containing component, it stops, but on certain browser zoom levels it starts again.

It seems like it is a weird combo of padding, browser zoom, and data size.

Anyone had similar issues?

I tried updating to the newest available version, but the bug is still present.
If I set the rotateXAxisTicks to false, the problem disappears, but then the data in the legends overlap.
I did not find anything similar in the issues section of the github project.